# React: Cross-Origin Blocked locally

Tags: reactjs, cross-origin-read-blocking

this is the first time i write on Stack Overflow.

I'm trying to use React locally using babel but when i try to execute it in the browser i got the cross-origin request blocked error.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Test React</title>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" ></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.js" ></script>
    <script type ="text/babel" src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="root"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

What i need to do ?

Comment: What request exactly is blocked? Provide details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [Create react app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) to create a React Application

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

It will fix all this errors

Comment: Thanks a lot. I also tried to upload the content of the build folder online and it works.